# Can we restrict operation of Git repo link/unlink in Azure Data Factory (ADF)?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-role-environment

Our team have a data factory, which is linked with one git repo having collaboration branch as 'Develop'. Many times, someone unlinks git repo attached to ADF and that causes issues to other team members. Due to this, sometimes git repo gets configured with wrong info (like collaboration branch as 'main' instead of 'Develop').

Is there a way or azure role using which we can restrict that link/unlink access?

Comment: have a look at this.. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-roles-permissions. You need to restrict users to unlink the repo.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict operation of Git repo in Azure data factory. You can set up your factory such that not every contributor has equal permissions.

To allow only authorized people to publish to the Data Factory, assign Data Factory **Contributor** role on the resource group that contains Data Factory.

For more information on permissions, see [Roles and permissions for Azure Data Factory.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-roles-permissions)

Also refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/source-control#permissions)